# Django Error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'availability'

Tags: python, django

I have a cart view where I'm trying to check if the products added to the cart have even one item in the list that has `product.availability` set to False and work accordingly in Template, the problem is with accessing the product availability in cart object list, So how do I check the availability of products that people added to cart?

P.S I shortened the code for utils, I'll add more if needed for understanding

Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    availability = models.BooleanField()
```

Utils

```
def cookieCart(request):
    try:
        cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
    except:
        cart = {}
    items = []
    for i in cart:
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(id=i)
            item = {
                'product':{
                    'id':product.id,
                    'name':product.name,
                    'final_price':product.final_price,
                    'image_URL':product.image_URL,
                    'availability':product.availability,
                },
                    'quantity':cart[i]["quantity"],
                    'get_total':total,
                }
            items.append(item)
        except:
            pass

    return {"items": items}

def cartData(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        cookieData = cookieCart(request)
        items = cookieData['items']
    return {'items':items}
```

Views

```
def cart(request):
    data = cartData(request)
    #products added to cart
    items = data['items']

    #Checking if even one product added to cart has availability set to False
    available = all(x.availability for x in items)

    context = {'items': items, 'available': available}
```

Template

```
<p>{{items.product.name}}</p>
{% if available %}
    <a href="#">Checkout</a>
{% else %}
    <p>Out of stock</p>
{% endif %}
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\test\shop\views.py", line 101, in cart
    available = all(x.availability for x in items)
  File "D:\test\shop\views.py", line 101, in <genexpr>
    available = all(x.availability for x in items)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /shop/cart
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'availability'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error tells you is that you are trying to access a dict item as an attribute (`x.y` instead of `x['y']`). Also, you missed one level of depth (`product`).

This should be:

```
available = all(x['product']['availability'] for x in items)
```

That being said, as mentionned by @blhsing, you should rather do your queries in a single queryset

```
products = Product.objects.filter(pk__in=cart)
items = [
    {
        'product': p,
        'quantity': cart[p.pk],
        'get_total': p.final_price * cart[p.pk],
    }
    for p in products
}
available = all(x['product'].availability for x in items)
# or 
# available = all(p.availability for p in products)
# or
# available = not products.filter(availability=False).exists()
return {'items': items, 'available': available}
```

Additionally, you have to make sure that in both cases of your `if/else` in `cartData()`, `items` has a consistent data structure. Which is not the case here, as in the `if`, `items` is a `QuerySet` whereas in the `else`, `items` is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: `available = all(x['availability'] for x in items)` this throws me a key error `availability`, I do appreciate your suggestion for having the same data structure for cartData, I'll give u an up for that, but following single queryset for this project would be a massive pain as of now! I really do appreciate your answer, thx! I now do understand the problem with `x.availability` but now then why is it throwing me the current error? any idea? thx again!

Comment: @betty_ `x['product']['availability']`...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an ad-hoc dict that does have the necessary `availability` attribute, you should simply return a `QuerySet` of `Product` objects after filtering products by IDs:

```
def cookieCart(request):
    try:
        cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
    except:
        cart = {}
    return {"items": Product.objects.filter(id__in=cart)}
```

Comment: yeah, it works but every other data related to the "items" context variable disappears, how do I fix it? thx!

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, in the cookieCart function you are appending to the items list a dictionary, not a Product object.

Change to:

```
def cookieCart(request):
    try:
        cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
    except:
        cart = {}
    items = []
    for i in cart:
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(id=i)            
            items.append(product)
        except:
            pass

    return {"items": items}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part is creating issue

```
def cookieCart(request):
    try:
        cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
    except:
        cart = {}
    items = []
    for i in cart:
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(id=i)
            item = {
                'product':{
                    'id':product.id,
                    'name':product.name,
                    'final_price':product.final_price,
                    'image_URL':product.image_URL,
                    'availability':product.availability,
                },
                }
            items.append(item)
        except:
            pass

    return {"items": items} # here your items is like this {"items": [{'product':{'id':product.id,'name':product.name,'final_price':product.final_price,'image_URL':product.image_URL,'availability':product.availability}}]}
```

Since error is suggesting that you picked item from COOKIES

**Now since you are looping as `all(x.availability for x in items)`
x will look like `{price: {...}}` which is dict object thatswhy it is saying that dict object has no attribute availability**

For resolving this issue use `SimpleNameSpace` like this

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

def cookieCart(request):
    try:
        cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
    except:
        cart = {}
    items = []
    for i in cart:
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(id=i)
            item = SimpleNamespace(**{
                    'id':product.id,
                    'name':product.name,
                    'final_price':product.final_price,
                    'image_URL':product.image_URL,
                    'availability':product.availability,
                })
            items.append(item)
        except:
            pass

    return {"items": items}
```

For optimised way
you can check @blhsing solution

Comment: I tried your way too, the entire cart goes empty even if there's products, no status error tho, I added two extra lines of code in utils, please have a look and thx!